# log4j appending to multiple files based on the log message content

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Can we append to multiple log files based on the log event content?.. Seems like once we loaded the config we can't change them in runtime?..

I have tried the following.

In an extended class of DailyRollingFileAppender's  subAppend, tried to change the output file location, using setFile().

Is there any other way to achieve this?.

Comment: Use the [MDC](https://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/NDCvsMDC) Luke!

Comment: FYI `Seems like once we loaded the config we can't change them in runtime?` this statement is incorrect.

Comment: @UUIIUI It changed first time what I have added in the log4j.properties file, then didn't change.

Comment: but it can be possible